# CSS3 equivalent to jQuery slideUp and slideDown?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

My application is performing poorly with jQuery's slideDown and slideUp. I'm looking to use a CSS3 equivalent in browsers which support it.

Is it possible, using CSS3 transitions, to change an element from `display: none;` to `display: block;` while sliding the item down or up?

Comment: I think you would keep the display:block, but just adjust the width from the desired amount to 0.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#youritem .fade.in {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}

#youritem .fade.out {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(startYposition);
    } 
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(endYposition);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(startYposition);
    } 
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(endYposition);
    }
}
```

**Example - Slide and Fade:**

This slides and animates the opacity - not based on height of the container, but on the top/coordinate. 
[View example](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Paa/)

**Example - Auto-height/No Javascript:**  Here is a live sample, not needing height - dealing with automatic height and no javascript.
 [View example](http://jsfiddle.net/nB5Du/)

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Šime From my first look at it, I'd say just give your element class="fade" and add class in when you'd like a fade in, out when you'd like a fade out.

Comment: @Šime - I've included two samples for you to use

Comment: I modified the second example (auto-height/no JavaScript) so only the barebones styles to get the effect were in place. http://jsfiddle.net/OlsonDev/nB5Du/251/

Comment: to newer readers, don't waste your time with these

Comment: @Barbz_YHOOL Can we have the reason?

Answer (score 20):

I changed your solution, so that it works in all modern browsers:

css snippet:

```
-webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
```

js snippet:

```
    var clone = $('#this').clone()
                .css({'position':'absolute','visibility':'hidden','height':'auto'})
                .addClass('slideClone')
                .appendTo('body');

    var newHeight = $(".slideClone").height();
    $(".slideClone").remove();
    $('#this').css('height',newHeight + 'px');
```

here's the full example http://jsfiddle.net/RHPQd/

Comment: Not sure who `-2` this, after 7 years, still work like a charm. Except that I recreate this with Vanilla JS. `+1`  from me.

Comment: Hi @JensT, I always thought jQuery made a 0-second auto-height or a clone as you did to measure the real default height, is it so?
I think the clone could not be 100% perfect, as appending it to the body doesn't guarantee to keep the same layout of the cloned element.

Comment: It seems that clone is not always needed with newer jQuery versions: Although the div has not set a height (i.e. height: auto), this.css("height") returns a pixel value, e.g. "90px". So it seems $("#this").css("height") seems to call $("#this").height() internally withouth displaying it (so maybe height() does a clone?)? tested with jQuery 3.7.0 and 3.4.1, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2yp9n3z8/ Anyone know the reason? One can use this to only do the clone part if a computed height is not available.

Answer (score 9):

So I've gone ahead and answered my own question :)

@True's answer regarded transforming an element to a specific height. The problem with this is I don't know the height of the element (it can fluctuate).

I found other solutions around which used max-height as the transition but this produced a very jerky animation for me.

My solution below works only in WebKit browsers.

Although not purely CSS, it involves transitioning the height, which is determined by some JS.

```js
$('#click-me').click(function() {
  var height = $("#this").height();
  if (height > 0) {
    $('#this').css('height', '0');
  } else {
    $("#this").css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'visibility': 'hidden',
      'height': 'auto'
    });
    var newHeight = $("#this").height();
    $("#this").css({
      'position': 'static',
      'visibility': 'visible',
      'height': '0'
    });
    $('#this').css('height', newHeight + 'px');
  }
});
```

```css
#this {
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
  max-height: 9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #BBBBBB;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

#click-me {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="click-me">click me</p>
<div id="this">here<br />is<br />a<br />bunch<br />of<br />content<br />sdf</div>
<div>always shows</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUjAH/6/)

Comment: Yeah, my code below doesn't require height as it uses the y-coordinate.  But you didn't mention that you needed something with a height dependency :)  You could always do a margin transition, etc.. But it appears you have what you're looking for, no?

Comment: @True do you think you could explain what you mean by a margin transition?

Comment: Added sample for positioning, will add the margining

Comment: Also added margin/no javsacript example

Answer (score 9):

Getting height transitions to work can be a bit tricky mainly because you have to know the height to animate for. This is further complicated by padding in the element to be animated.

Here is what I came up with:

use a style like this:

```
    .slideup, .slidedown {
        max-height: 0;            
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    }
    .slidedown {            
        max-height: 60px ;  // fixed width                  
    }
```

Wrap your content into another container so that the container you're sliding has no padding/margins/borders:

```
  <div id="Slider" class="slideup">
    <!-- content has to be wrapped so that the padding and
            margins don't effect the transition's height -->
    <div id="Actual">
            Hello World Text
        </div>
  </div>
```

Then use some script (or declarative markup in binding frameworks) to trigger the CSS classes.

```
  $("#Trigger").click(function () {
    $("#Slider").toggleClass("slidedown slideup");
  });
```

Example here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/uhChl94nLhrWCYVhRBUF?p=preview

This works fine for fixed size content. For a more generic soltution you can use code to figure out the size of the element when the transition is activated. The following is a jQuery plug-in that does just that:

```
$.fn.slideUpTransition = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.css("max-height", "0");
        $el.addClass("height-transition-hidden");
    });
};

$.fn.slideDownTransition = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.removeClass("height-transition-hidden");

        // temporarily make visible to get the size
        $el.css("max-height", "none");
        var height = $el.outerHeight();

        // reset to 0 then animate with small delay
        $el.css("max-height", "0");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $el.css({
                "max-height": height
            });
        }, 1);
    });
};
```

which can be triggered like this:

$("#Trigger").click(function () {

```
    if ($("#SlideWrapper").hasClass("height-transition-hidden"))
        $("#SlideWrapper").slideDownTransition();
    else
        $("#SlideWrapper").slideUpTransition();
});
```

against markup like this:

```
<style>
#Actual {
    background: silver;
    color: White;
    padding: 20px;
}

.height-transition {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    overflow-y: hidden;            
}
.height-transition-hidden {            
    max-height: 0;            
}
</style>
<div id="SlideWrapper" class="height-transition height-transition-hidden">
    <!-- content has to be wrapped so that the padding and
        margins don't effect the transition's height -->
    <div id="Actual">
     Your actual content to slide down goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Wpcgjs3FS4ryrhQUAOcU?p=preview

I wrote this up recently in a blog post if you're interested in more detail:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Feb/22/Using-CSS-Transitions-to-SlideUp-and-SlideDown

Comment: This is the most elegant solution as to me.
And if needed jQuery can be easily removed. One can toggle a class in vanila JS as:
`document.getElementById("Slider").classList.toggle("slidedown");`

Answer (score 8):

why not to take advantage of modern browsers css transition and make things simpler and fast using more css and less jquery

[Here is the code for sliding up and down](http://jsbin.com/tacir/6/edit?html,css,js,output)

[Here is the code for sliding left to right](http://jsbin.com/wirod/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Similarly we can change the sliding from  top to bottom or right to left by changing transform-origin and transform: scaleX(0) or transform: scaleY(0) appropriately.

Comment: I know this answers was placed in 2014 but I cannot recommend using this answer if you want to push elements below it down or up since the parent container will stake up the height in the browser

Comment: That can be solved by punting the element on position absolute @Ellisan, for example, is perfect for menu's effects

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the [jQuery Transit Plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) which uses the CSS3 transform property, which works great on mobile devices due to the fact that most support hardware acceleration to give that native look and feel.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5BBAt/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="moveMe">
    <button class="moveUp">Move Me Up</button>
    <button class="moveDown">Move Me Down</button>
    <button class="setUp">Set Me Up</button>
    <button class="setDown">Set Me Down</button>
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".moveUp").on("click", function() {
    $(".moveMe").transition({ y: '-=5' });
});

$(".moveDown").on("click", function() {
    $(".moveMe").transition({ y: '+=5' });
});

$(".setUp").on("click", function() {
    $(".moveMe").transition({ y: '0px' });
});

$(".setDown").on("click", function() {
    $(".moveMe").transition({ y: '200px' });
});
```

Comment: Does this enable you to transition to an element's natural height using auto? eg. $(".moveMe").transition({height: 'auto'})

Comment: I wish they'd override the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods with this plugin. That'd be really nice

Comment: This is awesome BTW. Thanks for adding this answer!

Answer (score 2):

Aight fam, after some research and experimenting, I think the best approach is to have the thing's height at `0px`, and let it transition to an exact height. You get the exact height with JavaScript. The JavaScript isn't doing the animating, it's just changing the height value. Check it:

```js
function setInfoHeight() {
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('.info').each(function () {
      var current = $(this);
      var closed = $(this).height() == 0;
      current.show().height('auto').attr('h', current.height() );
      current.height(closed ? '0' : current.height());
    });
  });
```

Whenever the page loads or is resized, the element with class `info` will get its `h` attribute updated. Then you could have a button trigger the `style="height: __"` to set it to that previously set `h` value.

```
function moreInformation() {
  $('.icon-container').click(function() {
    var info = $(this).closest('.dish-header').next('.info'); // Just the one info
    var icon = $(this).children('.info-btn'); // Select the logo

    // Stop any ongoing animation loops. Without this, you could click button 10
    // times real fast, and watch an animation of the info showing and closing
    // for a few seconds after
    icon.stop();
    info.stop();

    // Flip icon and hide/show info
    icon.toggleClass('flip');

    // Metnod 1, animation handled by JS
    // info.slideToggle('slow');

    // Method 2, animation handled by CSS, use with setInfoheight function
    info.toggleClass('active').height(icon.is('.flip') ? info.attr('h') : '0');

  });
};
```

Here's the styling for the `info` class.

```css
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1em;
  transition: height 0.6s, padding 0.6s;
  &.active {
    border-bottom: $thin-line;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

I used this on one of my projects so class names are specific. You can change them up however you like.

The styling might not be supported cross-browser. Works fine in chrome.

Below is the live example for this code. Just click on the `?` icon to start the animation

## [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cruznunez/pen/PzmdPE)

Answer (score 2):

Variant without JavaScript. Only CSS.

CSS:

```
.toggle_block {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.toggle_block .toggle_flag {
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left: -1000px;
}
.toggle_block .toggle_key {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
         -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
            transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.toggle_block .content {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
         -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
            transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.toggle_block .content .toggle_close {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.toggle_block .toggle_flag:checked ~ .toggle_key {
    background: #dfd;
}
.toggle_block .toggle_flag:checked ~ .content {
    max-height: 1000px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle_block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_1" class="toggle_flag">
    <label for="toggle_1" class="toggle_key">clicker</label>
    <div class="content">
        Text 1<br>
        Text 2<br>
        <label for="toggle_1" class="toggle_close">close</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For next block only change ID and FOR attributes in html.

Answer (score 0):

you can't make easisly a slideup slidedown with css3 tha's why I've turned JensT script into a plugin with javascript fallback and callback.

in this way if you have a modern brwowser you can use the css3 csstransition. if your browser does not support it gracefuly use the old fashioned slideUp slideDown.

```
 /* css */
.csstransitions .mosneslide {
  -webkit-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

the plugin

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.mosne_slide = function (
    options) {
    // set default option values
    defaults = {
        delay: 750,
        before: function () {}, // before  callback
        after: function () {} // after callback;
    }
    // Extend default settings
    var settings = $.extend({},
        defaults, options);
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        //on after
        settings.before.apply(
            $this);
        var height = $this.height();
        var width = $this.width();
        if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
            // modern browsers
            if (height > 0) {
                $this.css(
                    'height',
                    '0')
                    .addClass(
                        "mosne_hidden"
                );
            } else {
                var clone =
                    $this.clone()
                    .css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'visibility': 'hidden',
                        'height': 'auto',
                        'width': width
                    })
                    .addClass(
                        'mosne_slideClone'
                )
                    .appendTo(
                        'body'
                );
                var newHeight =
                    $(
                        ".mosne_slideClone"
                )
                    .height();
                $(
                    ".mosne_slideClone"
                )
                    .remove();
                $this.css(
                    'height',
                    newHeight +
                    'px')
                    .removeClass(
                        "mosne_hidden"
                );
            }
        } else {
            //fallback
            if ($this.is(
                ":visible"
            )) {
                $this.slideUp()
                    .addClass(
                        "mosne_hidden"
                );
            } else {
                $this.hide()
                    .slideDown()
                    .removeClass(
                        "mosne_hidden"
                );
            }
        }
        //on after
        setTimeout(function () {
            settings.after
                .apply(
                    $this
            );
        }, settings.delay);
    });
}
})(jQuery);;
```

how to use it

```
/* jQuery */
$(".mosneslide").mosne_slide({
    delay:400,
    before:function(){console.log("start");},
    after:function(){console.log("done");}
});
```

you can find a demo page here
http://www.mosne.it/playground/mosne_slide_up_down/

Comment: This isn't an answer, a answer contains more than just a link.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this for slide up slide down with animation 
give your **height

        @keyframes slide_up{
            from{
                min-height: 0;
                height: 0px;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to{
                height: 560px;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @keyframes slide_down{
            from{
                height: 560px;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            to{
                min-height: 0;
                height: 0px;
                opacity: 0;
            } 
        }
```