# animation using javascript - how to move an object upwards

Tags: javascript

Following is my code, there is a small box inside a container box, on click of button, it animates to down and hits the bottom of the container, and then it should rise up from there. But instead it starts flickering rapidly at the same place. Pls tell me how to rise the box once it hits the bottom .

```
    <style>
        #myContainer {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        background: yellow;
       }
      #myAnimation {
        width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       position: absolute;
       background: red;
      }
 </style>
  <p>
      <button id=button>Click Me</button> 

 </p>

  <div id ="myContainer">
         <div id ="myAnimation">Fish</div>
   </div>

  <script>
   button =document.getElementById("button");
   button.onclick = function() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
var pos = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame() {
    /*if (pos == 350) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } 
    else*/

        if(pos<175)

    {
        pos++;
        elem.style.top = 2*pos + 'px';
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
    else
    {
            pos--;
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        elem.style.right = pos + 'px';
             }
      }
   } 
   </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 equivalent to jQuery slideUp and slideDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072526/css3-equivalent-to-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown)

Answer (score 0):

Hi [made](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/11/) a little solution, you need a switch to made up untill go top, and reveerse to bottom.

```
button =document.getElementById("button");
   button.onclick = function() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
var pos = 0, up=false;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

function frame() {
console.log(up, pos);
    /*if (pos == 350) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } 
    else*/

        if(pos<175 && !up)

    {
        pos++;
        if(pos===175) up=true;
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
    else
    {
            pos--;
            if(pos<=0) up=false;
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
             }
      }
   }
```