# Responsive menu was created on jquery. I need to convert jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Guys, please help me to repeat this functionality in pure javascript.
I like how this menu works, but I can't figure it out with jquery.
Or if someone has a specification on how to implement jquery functionality in pure javascript, I would be very grateful.

---

Hello!
Guys, please help me to repeat this functionality in pure javascript.
I like how this menu works, but I can't figure it out with jquery.
Or if someone has a specification on how to implement jquery functionality in pure javascript, I would be very grateful.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //the trigger on hover when cursor directed to this class
    $(".core-menu li").hover(
    function(){
      //i used the parent ul to show submenu
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
    }, 
      //when the cursor away 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).slideUp('fast');
    });
  //this feature only show on 600px device width
    $(".hamburger-menu").click(function(){
      $(".burger-1, .burger-2, .burger-3").toggleClass("open");
        $(".core-menu").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#f2f2f2;
}
.main-menu {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background:#0e0e0e;
}
.container-menu {
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.main-menu:before,.main-menu:after{
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}
.core-menu {
  text-align:center;
  font:normal normal normal 1em/1 Roboto, sans-serif;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.core-menu li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.core-menu li a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:1em;
}
.core-menu li a:hover {
  background:#38a201;
}
li span.toggle {
  padding-left:1em;
}
.toggle:before {
  content:"\f107";
  font:normal normal normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;
}
.dropdown {
  position:absolute;
  width:230px;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  text-align:left;
  display:none;
}
.dropdown li {
  display:block;
  }
.dropdown li a {
  display:block;
}
.dropdown2 {
  position:absolute;
  width:230px;
  background:#2d2d2d;
  text-align:left;
  display:none;
  right:-100%;
  top:0;
}
.dropdown2 li {
  display:block;
  }
.dropdown2 li a {
  display:block;
}
li span.toggle2 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.toggle2:before {
  content:"\f105";
  font:normal normal normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;
}
.hamburger-menu {
  padding:1em;
  display:none;
  font:normal normal normal 16px/1 Roboto;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

@media (max-width:720px) {
  .main-menu {
    height:50px;
  }
  .container-menu {
    width:100%;
  }
  .navigation {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
  .core-menu {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    background:#1a1a1a;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
  }
  
  .core-menu li {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
  }
  .core-menu li a{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
  }
  .hamburger-menu {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:60px;
    float:none;
    width:100%;
  }
  .burger-1, .burger-2, .burger-3 {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:3px;
  border-radius:30px;
  right:0;
  margin-right:25px;
  background:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:.2s ease;
    -ms-transition:.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:.2s ease;
    -o-transition:.2s ease;
  transition:.2s ease; 
  }
  .burger-1 {
  top:15px;
  }
  .burger-2 {
  top:23px;
  }
  .burger-3 {
  top:31px;
  }
  .burger-1.open, .burger-2.open, .burger-3.open {
  -webkit-transition:.2s ease;
  -ms-transition:.2s ease;
  -moz-transition:.2s ease;
  -o-transition:.2s ease;
    transition:.2s ease;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
  }
  .burger-1.open {
    top:25px;
    width:23px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg); 
  }
  .burger-2.open {
    opacity:0;
  }
  .burger-3.open {
    top:25px;
    width:23px;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .dropdown {
    width:100%;
    background:#0e0e0e;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
  }
  .dropdown2 {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main-menu' class='main-menu'>
  <div class='container-menu'>
    <nav class='navigation'>
      <span class='hamburger-menu'>Navigate
        <span class='burger-1'></span>
        <span class='burger-2'></span>
        <span class='burger-3'></span>
      </span>
      <ul class='core-menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>Product<span class='toggle'></span></a>
          <ul class='dropdown'>
            <li><a href='#'>Windows 10<span class='toggle2'></span></a></a>
              <ul class='dropdown2'>
                <li><a href='#'>Windows 10 Pro</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Windows 10 Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Profesional</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Windows Phone</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Laptop</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Featured<span class='toggle'></a>
        <ul class='dropdown'>
            <li><a href='#'>Cortana</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Xboct</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Microsoft Edge</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Devices</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [you might not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - I suppose it is the slideUp, slideDown, and slideToggle the OP is struggling with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 equivalent to jQuery slideUp and slideDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072526/css3-equivalent-to-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear why you cannot use jQuery if the solution you posted is working. Is there a specific reason you cannot use jQuery?